# Why is the free product of a group with itself not isomorphic to itself?

Tags: group-theory, definition, free-product

I've been recently introduced to the definition of free product of groups, and I'm struggling to identify the details of its precise definition. In particular, it seems to me from the definition I've seen that a free product of a group $G$ with itself, $G * G$, would be isomorphic to $G$ again. But I've seen that we speak of such things as $F_n$, the free product of $\mathbb{Z}$ with itself $n$ times, so obviously I must be wrong.

Below I'll write the definition of free product **as I've understood it**, trying to be as precise as possible and as formal as is pragmatic, and then show how (I think) that definition leads to the aforementioned result. **I'd like to know what part of the definition I got wrong.**

### Definition of free product

Let $(G, \cdot_G)$ and $(H, \cdot_H)$ be groups. The free product of $(G, \cdot_G)$ and $(H, \cdot_H)$, denoted $(G, \cdot_G) * (H, \cdot_H)$, is the group $(G * H, \cdot_{G * H})$, where $G * H$ is the set of reduced words on $G$ and $H$, and $\cdot_{G * H}$ is the operation given by concatenation followed by reduction. Precise definitions of each are given below.

- The set of reduced words on $G$ and $H$, denoted $G * H$, is defined as $r_{G,H}[W(G \cup H)]$, where $W(\cdot)$ denotes the set of words on a set and $r_{G,H}$ is the function that maps each word to its reduced form. That is, it is the image of the set of words on $G \cup H$ under the reduction map $r_{G, H}$.

  - Let $S$ be a set. The set of words on $S$, denoted $W(S)$, is defined as the set of finite but nonempty (ordered) tuples in elements of $S$. That is:
    $$W(S) := \{ (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0},\quad \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}\ x_i \in S \}$$
    (The words are usually denoted as a formal product $x_1x_2\cdots x_n$, but I'm going to avoid this notation here to be clear how they are formally defined and so as to not be tempted to confuse the formal product with the product in $G$ in the next section.) Thus, in particular: $$W(G \cup H) = \{ (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}_{> 0},\quad \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}\ (x_i \in G \lor x_i \in H) \}$$
  - The reduction map $r_{G,H}$ is the function $r_{G,H} \colon W(G \cup H) \to W(G \cup H)$ that maps each word to its reduced form. The reduced form of a word is the word that we obtain by **repeatedly** applying any of the following operations until we can no longer apply any of them.

    1. Omit the identity of $G$, $1_G$, from a word of lenght greater than 1. That is, transform a word of the form $(x_1, \ldots, x_{i - 1}, 1_G, x_{i + 1}, \ldots, x_n)$ (with $n > 1$) into the word $(x_1, \ldots, x_{i - 1}, x_{i + 1}, \ldots, x_n)$.
    2. Omit the identity of $H$, $1_H$, from a word of lenght greater than 1. That is, transform a word of the form $(x_1, \ldots, x_{i - 1}, 1_H, x_{i + 1}, \ldots, x_n)$ (with $n > 1$) into the word $(x_1, \ldots, x_{i - 1}, x_{i + 1}, \ldots, x_n)$.
    3. Replace two consecutive elements of $G$, $g_1$ and $g_2$, with their product $g_1 \cdot_G g_2$. That is, transform a word of the form $(x_1, \ldots, x_{i - 1}, g_1, g_2, x_{i + 2}, \ldots, x_n)$, where $g_1, g_2 \in G$, into the word $(x_1, \ldots, x_{i - 1}, g_1 \cdot_G g_2, x_{i + 2}, \ldots, x_n)$.
    4. Replace two consecutive elements of $H$, $h_1$ and $h_2$, with their product $h_1 \cdot_H h_2$. That is, transform a word of the form $(x_1, \ldots, x_{i - 1}, h_1, h_2, x_{i + 2}, \ldots, x_n)$, where $h_1, h_2 \in H$, into the word $(x_1, \ldots, x_{i - 1}, h_1 \cdot_H h_2, x_{i + 2}, \ldots, x_n)$.

    (I omit the proof that there is a unique reduced form, etc.)
- The operation $\cdot_{G * H}$ is defined by concatenating and then reducing. That is, if $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and $(y_1, \ldots, y_m)$ are elements of $G * H$, then: $$(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \cdot_{G*H} (y_1, \ldots, y_m) := r_{G,H}\big((x_1, \ldots, x_n, y_1, \ldots, y_n)\big)$$

### Proof of $G * G \cong G$ from the above definition

Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a group, and consider the free product of $G$ with itself, $(G * G, \cdot_{G * G})$. By the above definition, the set $G * G$ is the set $r_{G,G}[W(G \cup G)] = r_{G,G}[W(G)]$, so it is the set of reduced words in $G$. Let us consider an arbitrary element of $W(G)$, which will be of the form $(g_1, \ldots, g_n)$ with $g_i \in G$. Its reduced form will just be the 1-tuple $(g,)$ where $g = g_1 \cdot g_2  \cdots g_n$. Indeed, since all the elements of the word are in $G$, we can apply operation 3 above (or operation 4, which is the same in this case since $H$ "is" $G$) repeatedly until we're left with a word of length 1:
$$(g_1, g_2, g_3 \ldots, g_n) \rightsquigarrow (g_1g_2, g_3 \ldots, g_n) \rightsquigarrow \cdots \rightsquigarrow (g_1 \cdots g_n,)$$
Since the set of all finite products of elements in $G$ is just $G$ again, we thus have that $G*G = r[W(G)] = \{(g,) \mid g \in G\}$. Moreover, $G$ is isomorphic to $G * G$ via the natural map $\phi \colon G \to G*G$ defined by $g \mapsto (g,)$. Indeed, if $g_1, g_2 \in G$, then by what we have said about reduced forms: $$\phi(g_1 \cdot g_2) = (g_1 \cdot g_2,) = r_{G,G}\big((g_1, g_2)\big) \doteq (g_1,) \cdot_{G*G} (g_2,) = \phi(g_1) \cdot_{G*G} \phi(g_2)$$ so $\phi$ is a homomorphism (and $\phi$ is clearly bijective).

### Guess

My guess is that the union in the above definition should be disjoint, i.e. that $G*H$ should be defined as $r[W(G \sqcup H)]$, adjusting the rest of the definition accordingly?

Comment: Yes it is disjoint union

Comment: @DietrichBurde I know that the result is false, but the proof is valid, so I just want to know what part of the definition is incorrect.

Comment: The definition never allows you to reduce words between $G$ and $H$. You reduce them separately and concatenate, but further reductions aren't included as a step. You could define it using the disjoint union instead to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I'm not sure I understand. After concatenation, we must always reduce, otherwise we might not get a word in reduced form: e.g. $a^nb^m$ concatenated with $b^ka^\ell$ is $a^nb^mb^ka^\ell$, but this is not in reduced form, so we must apply reduction to get $a^nb^{m + k}a^\ell$.

Comment: @Anakhand where does it say to do that? Step 3 and 4 treat $G$ and $H$ separately but there is no step 5 to further reduce them. Note that that would be an exceptional rule for certain situations where $H$ or $G$ is a subgroup of the other but the free produce is defined for any two group which normally cannot be reduced.

Comment: @CyclotomicField The final sentence of your comment is incomprehensible! I think the OP is correct. With that exact definition we get $G*G = G$. But the definition is wrong - the free factors have to be disjoint.

Comment: @CyclotomicField That's the definition (as I've understood it) of the group operation on $G*G$: concatenate and then reduce (otherwise $G*G$ is not even closed under this operation, because $G*G$ is the set of words *in reduced form*). Also note that the steps I've listed aren't meant to say "do 1 then 2 then 3 then 4", but rather "do any finite combination with repetitions of 1, 2, 3, and 4", as the paragraph above the list says. (The numbers just name the steps.) Otherwise we wouldn't be able to reduce $(a, a, a)$ into $(a^3,)$ because we would only be allowed to do step 3 once.

Comment: @DerekHolt I'm trying to convey the fact that free products are defined on any two groups and having exceptional rules for word reduction in the specific case when $H$ and $G$ are related would be weird.

Comment: @Anakhand it would be weird and it's weird that they didn't just use the disjoint union instead of specifically making you track the elements of each group mentally but I don't think the definition is wrong just needlessly confusing.

Comment: Your final guess is correct. The error in the definition is at the very top. You need to construct words in $G\amalg H$, not on $G\cup H$. The precise underlying sets of your groups should **not** affect what their free product is: their free product should only depend on their "group-theoretic" properties, not how they are explicitly constructed. By considering $G\cup H$ instead of a disjoint union, you force considerations about what **precisely** the constructions of $G$ and $H$ are *as sets*, and that cannot possibly be a correct definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, the words should be over the *disjoint* union of $G$ and $H$. For the sake of completeness, I'm posting an answer to write down what the correct definition would be.

### Definition of free product

Let $(G, \cdot_G)$ and $(H, \cdot_H)$ be groups. The free product of $(G, \cdot_G)$ and $(H, \cdot_H)$, denoted $(G, \cdot_G) * (H, \cdot_H)$, is the group $(G * H, \cdot_{G * H})$, where $G * H$ is the set of reduced words on $G$ and $H$, and $\cdot_{G * H}$ is the operation given by concatenation followed by reduction. Precise definitions of each are given below.

- The set of reduced words on $G$ and $H$, denoted $G * H$, is defined as $r_{G,H}[W(G \sqcup H)]$, where $W(\cdot)$ denotes the set of words on a set and $r_{G,H}$ is the function that maps each word to its reduced form. That is, it is the image of the set of words on $G \cup H$ under the reduction map $r_{G, H}$.

  - Let $S$ be a set. The set of words on $S$, denoted $W(S)$, is defined as the set of finite (ordered) tuples in elements of $S$. That is:
    $$W(S) := \{ (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0},\quad \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}\ x_i \in S \}$$
    Thus, in particular:
    $$W(G \sqcup H) = \{ (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0},\quad \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}\quad (\exists g \in G\ x_i = (g, 1))\ \veebar\ (\exists h \in H\ x_i = (h, 2))\}$$
  - The reduction map $r_{G,H}$ is the function $r_{G,H} \colon W(G \sqcup H) \to W(G \sqcup H)$ that maps each word to its reduced form. The reduced form of a word is the word that we obtain by **repeatedly** applying any of the following operations until we can no longer apply any of them.

    1. Omit a letter that is the identity in $G$ or in $H$ from a word. That is, transform a word of the form $(x_1, \ldots, x_{i - 1}, (1_G, 1), x_{i + 1}, \ldots, x_n)$ or $(x_1, \ldots, x_{i - 1}, (1_H, 2), x_{i + 1}, \ldots, x_n)$ into the word $(x_1, \ldots, x_{i - 1}, x_{i + 1}, \ldots, x_n)$.
    2. Replace two consecutive elements of the same group (either $G$ or $H$) with their product. That is, transform a word of the form $(x_1, \ldots, x_{i - 1}, (y_1, \iota), (y_2, \iota), x_{i + 2}, \ldots, x_n)$, where $y_1, y_2$ are both in $G$ or both in $H$ (since $\iota = \iota$) into the word $(x_1, \ldots, x_{i - 1}, (y_1 \cdot y_2, \iota), x_{i + 2}, \ldots, x_n)$, where $\cdot$ denotes correspondingly either $\cdot_G$ or $\cdot_H$.

    (I omit the proof that there is a unique reduced form, etc.)
- The operation $\cdot_{G * H}$ is defined by concatenating and then reducing. That is, if $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and $(y_1, \ldots, y_m)$ are elements of $G * H$, then: $$(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \cdot_{G*H} (y_1, \ldots, y_m) := r_{G,H}\big((x_1, \ldots, x_n, y_1, \ldots, y_n)\big)$$

### Proof sketch that it is a group

- **Closure under the operation.** The product of two words is by definition the reduction of their concatenation, so it is also a word in reduced form.
- **Associativity.** The reduction map $r$ is "sub-idempotent", i.e. applying $r$ to any sub-word of a word and then applying it to the entire word is the same as just applying it to the entire word (details omitted). Thus:
  $$((x_1, \ldots, x_r) \cdot_{G*H} (y_1, \ldots, y_s)) \cdot_{G*H} (z_1, \ldots, z_t) = r(r((x_1, \ldots, x_r) \mid (y_1, \ldots, y_s)) \mid (z_1, \ldots, z_t)) = r((x_1, \ldots, x_r) \mid (y_1, \ldots, y_s) \mid (z_1, \ldots, z_t)) = r((x_1, \ldots, x_r) \mid r((y_1, \ldots, y_s) \mid (z_1, \ldots, z_t))) = (x_1, \ldots, x_r) \cdot_{G*H} ((y_1, \ldots, y_s) \cdot_{G*H} (z_1, \ldots, z_t))$$
  where $\mid$ denotes concatenation.
- **Identity.** The empty word $()$ is the identity, since concatenating with $()$ does nothing, and then reducing doesn't do anything either because the word was already in reduced form.
- **Inverses.** The inverse of $((x_1, \iota_1), \ldots, (x_n, \iota_n))$ is $((x_n^{-1}, \iota_n), \ldots, (x_1^{-1}, \iota_1))$.

Comment: What is the identity element of this group?

Comment: @DerekHolt Good point, I guess I should allow empty tuples so that the identity element can be that. (In the original post I deliberately avoided empty tuples so as to avoid having to mention special cases for the identity, e.g. $\phi$ should have been defined as $g \mapsto (g,)$ for non-identity $g$ and $1_G \mapsto ()$.)

Comment: Yes, in the standard definitions, the identity is the empty word. As it is, you seem to have two identities $(1_G,1)$ and $(1_H,2)$ which would have to represent the same group element, but that problem goes away if they both reduce to the empty word.